# Ignore or replace Handlebars blocks that don't compile

Tags: ember.js, javascript-framework, handlebars.js

In a handlebars template in Ember.js, I have blocks like the following:

```
{{content.some_attribute}}
{{content.some_other_attr}}
{{content.more_attr}}
```

Some of these attributes don't exist and I'm implementing them slowly.

Is there a way to get these templates to compile and either *ignore* the blocks that don't evaluate or better yet, *replace* them with a html element so they're easier to spot in the browser?

(the template is pretty large and it's being converted from ERB slowly,

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to get these templates to compile and either ignore the blocks that don't evaluate

Properties that don't exist are `undefined`, and don't get rendered at all. In other words `{{thisDoesNotExist}}` will simply be invisible -- it will compile just fine.

> or better yet, *replace* them with a html element so they're easier to spot in the browser

As Cory said, you could use a helper for this that checks for `undefined`, using [Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.html#method_registerBoundHelper).

Comment: i'm not too interested in bindings. the helper would act as a temporary thing to help me mark the places where undefined is. The template is an extensive spec doc, so being able to look at it in the browser and just look for e.g. blocks with a background-color,etc would make it a lot easier to go through and convert this doc from erb

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a perfect case for a handlebars helper. The helper could validate the value and return the value or the html that you desire.

Comment: never made a helper before, but doesn't look too complicated. Will try it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

### The following code should be used very carefully, since it has not been tested within an application.

A possible solution to replace the possible `undefined` value in a template is to overwrite `Ember.getPath`, which is used to lookup the value of a path in a template, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/hKK8p/:

```js
var getPath = Ember.getPath;
Ember.getPath = function(obj, path) {
    var value = getPath(obj, path);
    return (Ember.none(value) ? 'OMG %@ is not defined!!'.fmt(path) : value);
};
```

If this code would be used **temporarily** in an application, I would also restrict the check for `undefined` values to a specific `obj`. So something along those lines:

```js
App.objectWhichHasUndefinedProps = Ember.Object.create({
    ...
});

Ember.View.create({
    templateName: 'templateWithAttributes',
    objBinding: 'App.objectWhichHasUndefinedProps'
}).append();

var getPath = Ember.getPath;
Ember.getPath = function(obj, path) {
    var value = getPath(obj, path);
    if (obj === App.objectWhichHasUndefinedProps) {
        return (Ember.none(value) ? 'OMG %@ is not defined!!'.fmt(path) : value);
    }
    return value;
};
```

Comment: That is horrible and funny at the same time. ;-) I would expect that in practice, this will break plenty of internal Ember code though, won't it?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure if I like it either :) I haven't tried it within an app, but I guess strange things will happen. I better add a big red warning sign to my answer ...